# Callback from WCF to Flash (AS3)

Tags: c#, wcf, actionscript-3, flash, duplex

I have an client server software that uses WCF duplex channel to connect them.

Most of the communication is done from the client to the server but i also have some callbacks from the server to the client.

My problem begins with the fact that i need to allow flash client to consume that data from the server.

I added another endPoint with basicHttpBinding so the flash client will be able to connect to it and now i am stuck without a solution to the callback.

What is the best solution to allow duplex connection between the flash client and the server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution and now i am testing to see if it will fit my needs,

Long Puling between the flash client and my WCF service,

It means that the client will need to make a call to the server and the server will hold that connection and wont return until he will have an update (or if i will define some timeout for the connection)

After the client will receive an answer (return value) from that function he will make that call again.
This way i can simulate a callback from the server to the client,

Hope it will help someone.

When i will be done i will upload some code